# How to deal with more complex transformation distributions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Assume that X1, X2,..., Xn ($n\ge 2$) are simple random samples from a normal distribution $\mathrm{N}(\mu, 1)$, let $\overline{\mathbf{X}}=\frac{1}{\mathrm{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{\mathrm{n}} \mathrm{X}_{i}$. Which of the following four conclusions is wrong ($\chi^{2}$ and `ChiSquareDistribution[v]` have the same meaning)?

$$
\begin{array}{c}
&(A)&  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\mu\right)^{2} \; obeys \; \chi^{2} \; distribution \quad 
&(B)&   2\left(X_{n}-X_{1}\right)^{2}  \; obeys \; \chi^{2} \; distribution.\\
&(C)&  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\overline{\mathbf{X}}\right)^{2}  \; obeys \; \chi^{2} \; distribution. \quad 
&(D)&   \mathbf{n}(\overline{\mathbf{X}}-\mu)^{2}  \; obeys \; \chi^{2} \; distribution 
\end{array} $$

But I had trouble judging whether the conclusion of the first option was correct:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
 TransformedDistribution[ Sum[(x[i] - 1)^2, {i, 1, 2}], 
  Table[x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1, 1], {i, 1, 2}]]
Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], x], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]
```

The above code runs all the time. What should I do to deal with the complex conversion probability problem?

Comment: Sometimes breaking things up into separate steps works.  For example consider (A): `d1 = TransformedDistribution[(x - \[Mu])^2, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu], 1]]; n = 4; d = TransformedDistribution[Sum[x[i], {i, n}], Table[x[i] \[Distributed] d1, {i, n}]]`.  The result is `ChiSquareDistribution[4]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

For the first option,

```
TransformedDistribution[(x - μ), 
 x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, 1]]

(* NormalDistribution[0, 1] *)
```

For a sum of length 1

```
TransformedDistribution[x^2,
 x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]

(* ChiSquareDistribution[1] *)
```

By induction

```
TransformedDistribution[X + x,
 {X \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[m - 1],
  x \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[1]}]

(* ChiSquareDistribution[m] *)
```